# Python webscraping and getting contents of first div tag of its class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.3

I'm working with Python 3.3 and this website:
http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/

My goal is to read only the companies that are in the Upcoming IPO. It is in the div tag with div class="genTable thin floatL" There are two with this class, and the target data is in the first one.

Here is my code

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for divparent in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'genTable thin floatL'}) [0]: # I tried putting a [0] so it will only return divs in the first genTable thin floatL class
    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'ipo-cell-height'}):
        s = div.string
        if re.match(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$', s):
            div_next = div.find_next('div')
            print('{} - {}'.format(s, div_next.string))
```

I'd like it to return only

```
3/7/2014 - RECRO PHARMA, INC.
2/28/2014 - VARONIS SYSTEMS INC
2/27/2014 - LUMENIS LTD
2/21/2014 - SUNDANCE ENERGY AUSTRALIA LTD
2/21/2014 - SEMLER SCIENTIFIC, INC.
```

But it prints all div classes with the re.match specifications and multiple times as well. I tried inserting [0] on the for divparent loop to retrieve only the first one but this cause the repeating problem instead.

EDIT: Here is the updated code according to warunsl solution. This works.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

divparent = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'genTable thin floatL'})[0]
table= divparent.find('table')
for div in table.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'ipo-cell-height'}):
        s = div.string
        if re.match(r'\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$', s):
            div_next = div.find_next('div')
            print('{} - {}'.format(s, div_next.string))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that there are two elements that fit the `'class':'genTable thin floatL'` criteria. So running a for loop for it's first element does not make sense.

So replace your outer for loop with

```
divparent = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'genTable thin floatL'})[0]
```

Now you need not do a `soup.find_all` again. Doing so will search the entire document. You need to restrict the search to the `divparent`. So, you do:

```
table = divparent.find('table')
```

The remainder of the code to extract the dates and the company name would be the same, except that they will be with reference to the `table` variable.

```
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    for data in row.find_all('td'):
        print data.string
```

Hope it helps.